# How can I add a text label that is vertically and horizontally centered to a Grid I create in C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's what I have so far:

```
details.Children.Clear();
var grid = new Grid()
{
   HeightRequest = 50
};
grid.Children.Add(new Label { 
   Text = "00" 
});
details.Children.Add(grid);
```

But this doesn't centre the text in the Grid. Can someone give me advice on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try HorizontalOptions = Center and VerticalOptions = Center for the Label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of VerticalOptions and HorizontalOptions, like this:

```
details.Children.Clear();
var grid = new Grid()
{
   HeightRequest = 50
};
grid.Children.Add(new Label { 
   Text = "00" ,
   VerticalOptions="Center"
   HorizontalOptions="Center"
});
details.Children.Add(grid);
```

You may also apply this to your grid, if you want the grid centered.